# Xamarin support of SNI with Apple TLS (not Mono TLS)?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, tls1.2

We have a problems when calling our internal api servers via a Xamarin.iOS application.

Our reverse-proxy server return always a 403 HTTP Error. The server's logs indicate : "No hostname was provided via SNI for a name based virtual host".

With Mono TLS : no problem. But with Apple TLS it doesn't work. We have tested with all HTTP Client implentation : Managed Code, NSUrlSession and CFNetwork with same result.

I know that Apple TLS support SNI. Our web server provide content without problem when using Safari on iPhone.

But, with Xamarin and specially with Apple TLS, impossible.

Have you any idea ?

PS : we by-pass certificate validation

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback 
   += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => {return true;};
```

Comment: It is a bug, see my answer details and for Xamarin bug that I filed....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Using `NSUrlSession` (works fine with SNI):

```
webView = new WKWebView(new CGRect(40, 100, 400, 400), new WKWebViewConfiguration());
Add(webView);
button = new UIButton(UIButtonType.System);
button.Frame = new CGRect(40, 40, 100, 40);
button.SetTitle("Fetch", UIControlState.Normal);
Add(button);
button.TouchUpInside += async (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
{
    var url = new NSUrl("https://sni.velox.ch");
    var task = await NSUrlSession.SharedSession.CreateDataTaskAsync(url);
    webView.LoadHtmlString(NSString.FromData(task.Data, NSStringEncoding.UTF8), new NSUrl(""));
};
```

Or using `bob.sni.velox.ch` or `alice.sni.velox.ch`

```
TLS SNI Test Site: *.sni.velox.ch
Great! Your client [TLSv12wSNI/1.0 CFNetwork/808.0.1 Darwin/15.6.0]
sent the following TLS server name indication extension (RFC 6066) 
in its ClientHello (negotiated protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher suite: 
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384):

  sni.velox.ch

In your request, this header was included:
  Host: sni.velox.ch
```

#### Using HttpClient:

```
button.TouchUpInside += async (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
{
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (servicesender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var response = await client.GetAsync("https://sni.velox.ch");
    webView.LoadHtmlString(new NSString(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()), new NSUrl(""));
};
```

#### Using SSL/TLS Implementation set to `Mono TLS` (works fine with SNI):

```
TLS SNI Test Site: *.sni.velox.ch

Great! Your client [TLSv12wSNI/1.0 CFNetwork/808.0.1 Darwin/15.6.0]
sent the following TLS server name indication extension (RFC 6066) in
its ClientHello (negotiated protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher suite: 
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384):

  sni.velox.ch

In your request, this header was included:

  Host: sni.velox.ch
```

#### Using SSL/TLS Implementation set to `Apple TLS (default)`: (**BUG**)

#### **Bug: `your client did not send a TLS server name indication extension`**

```
TLS SNI Test Site: alice.sni.velox.ch

Unfortunately, your client did not send a TLS server name indication
extension (RFC 4366) in its ClientHello (negotiated protocol: TLSv1.2,
cipher suite: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384), so you're probably 
getting warnings about certificate name mismatches.
In your request, this header was included:

  Host: sni.velox.ch
```

#### Notes:

Personally we avoid `HttpClient` on iOS and always use the iOS  "native" networking classes/API: `NSUrlSession`, `NSURLConnection`, ....

Bug Filed : https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=43794